# Do Interceptors have to be beans?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

Inside of my class that extends `WebMvcConfigurerAdapter` I want to add Interceptors like this

```
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        super.addInterceptors(registry);
        registry.addInterceptor(new MyInterceptor());
    }
```

Would `MyInterceptor` have to be declared as a bean, or can I just instantiate it on my own like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to official documentation, your interceptors should be Spring beans if you declare them in the xml configuration.

Your called method :

```
InterceptorRegistration addInterceptor(HandlerInterceptor interceptor)
```

From https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html
 :

**org.springframework.web.servlet**

**Interface HandlerInterceptor**

> The interceptors themselves are defined as beans in the application
>   context, referenced by the mapping bean definition via its
>   "interceptors" property (in XML: a  of ).

**Update**

What javaguy refers is letting Spring make the instantiation of the bean.
It underlies that your interceptor follows the stateless principle.
To enable that, your interceptor should not have state (internal properties  which change during the interceptor execution).
As a general rule, when it is possible, processing classes should try to not keep state.

Here how you could create your singleton interceptor with Spring :

```
@Configuration
public class YourSpringConf{

  @Bean
    public HandlerInterceptor myInterceptor() {
       return new MyInterceptor();
    }
}
```

In this way, you will have a Bean named `myInterceptor` managed by Spring and you can inject it in the `addInterceptors()` method.

Comment: Thank you. It still seems like it could be up for debate though, because if you're setting them via XML the only option is to declare them as beans, whereas with Java we have the power to instantiate the classes ourselves.

Comment: I just tested with simply instantiating them like in my example, and so far everything is working the same as before (iI' migrating from xml to Java config)

Comment: xml configuration is verbose and create some indirections. So, indeed, it seems more relevant to use the java version to instantiate your bean.

Comment: @zero01alpha I edited my answer to explain what javaguy refers with an example and to give you more details

Comment: I would also add that the literal answer to my question is no, they do not actually HAVE to be declared as beans.

Comment: I agree with you : I think that the doc is not updated.  But they have to be declared as beans if you declare them in the xml configuration. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Would MyInterceptor have to be declared as a bean or can I just
>   instantiate it on my own like this?

Already answered by David, just adding one more point:

If there is a singleton object, then it is ALWAYS better to leave it for the Spring container to maintain/manage it as a singleton scoped bean (default scope), rather than developers manually using `new MyInterceptor()` and creating & ensuring single instance of the class.

This concept is applicable NOT only for `MyInterceptor`, rather needs to be followed for all singleton scoped objects (like Services, DAOs, Filters, etc..).

**Further Explanation:**

What I mean is that when you have taken the control (of creation) of few beans (like interceptors), then at some time of time, your application will end up in a messy state i.e., some of the singleton beans are maintained by Spring Container and some of the beans are created by developers using `new` operator (which can't be easily differentiated causing lots of confusion). So the best practice is that to leave the creation of all singleton-scoped beans (atleast) to the Spring container itself.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration. Can you please explain an example of how another instance of `MyInterceptor` could ever get created? I understand that Spring ensures "there can only be one", but how would another one ever be created? If I'm using the `new` keyword inside of a method that Spring only runs once, how could it ever happen again. Just curious!

Comment: What I mean is that when you are taking the control of creation of few beans (few like interceptors), then at some time of time, you will end up in a confusion (messy state) i.e., which singleton beans are maintained by Spring Container and which are created by developers can't be easily differentiated.